# Can we listen to specific keyed messages by Kafka Consumer

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

I am very much new to Kafka. I have a requirement, where I need to read only some specific messages.

For this, I will push a message to Kafka with some key and value. Is there a way we can subscribe a consumer to specific list of keys. So that when a message pushed to Kafka, the consumer would consume if the message has a key for which the consumer is listening.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can i consume based on specific condition in Kafka?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39634354/can-i-consume-based-on-specific-condition-in-kafka)

Comment: You might want to look into redis or 0mq, they both provide pub/sub which does fine grained filtering of messages on server, rather than client, side.

Answer (score 2):

The only way I can think of is that you can assign your consumer to partitions to which a publisher sends messages with keys you're interested in. You'd also need to write your own partitioner, that will allow you to send a message with a key X always to the same partition.

The easier way: write a consumer in a way that will process only messages you want.